# Should URDF in Gazebo tutorials be replaced with SDF?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Migrated from [ROS' community's website](http://goo.gl/j7srJ).

In [the QA thread "SDF vs URDF what should one use?"](http://goo.gl/GMujA) (on answers.gazebosim.org), `URDF` is not recommended on `gazebo` in favor of `SDF`. But from [the answer in this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/41294/gazebo-with-controller/?answer=41770#post-id-41770), sounds like URDF will still be supported on `gazebo`. Can we keep the tutorial using `URDF`?

---

A couple of comments there:

```
It would be better to have one standard (and also use the new version 
of Gazebo in ROS), would prevent a lot of problems. But URDF is also 
used in RVIZ which doesn't care about the extra proporties like 
friction. @davinci
```

2nd:

```
I'm in favour. I'm new and the learning curve is steep when I need to 
pull bits of advice off of gazebosim (usually SDF) and ros answers 
(URDF) and figure out what's valid where and in which version of Gazebo.
@Benjamin Blumer
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/853/should-urdf-in-gazebo-tutorials-be-replaced-with-sdf?/) by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 118 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-01-16**:
I'm in favour. I'm new and the learning curve is steep when I need to
pull bits of advice off of gazebosim (usually SDF) and ros answers
(URDF) and figure out what's valid where and in which version of Gazebo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks for the advice. We'll be migrating the documentation to use SDF. Our primary blocker right now is releasing a standalone library of SDF.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0